# Can't access public properties from MY_controller when extending from MX_Controller in HMVC

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-hmvc

I have implemented Codeigniter HMVC which works fine. Then I'm extending `MX_Controller` with `MY_Controller` to share functionality and properties between all my modules and to keep my code DRY.

But I noticed that while extending `MY_Controller` from `MX_Controller` I can no longer access the public properties from `MY_Controller` on any of the extended child classes.

Some sample code:

```
class MY_Controller extends MX_Controller {

    public $variable;

    function __contruct()
    {
        parent::__contruct();
        $this->variable = 'Foo';
    }
}
```

Then on any controller which I extend from MY_Controller:

```
class Foo extends MY_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function someFunction()
    {
       var_dump($this->variable);
    }

}
```

When I trying to access the public property `$variable` in any child controller I get `Null` or empty string.

I have searched high and low for this with no luck, my only guess is an issue with HMVC `MX_Controller`. Any Ideas?

Comment: Is there a spelling mistake in the first constructor? `__contruct()`

Comment: Yes Yan Berk, that was it. I noticed the issue that same day after getting a PHP error about it. I fixed it. What I never understood was, how can this be going on for days without yanking a php error like it did at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of checking, it was a simple mistake on my behalf. I had misspelled the name parent::__contruct on MY_Controller, it should be parent:__construct.